# Can't create ListViewLinearLayout

Tags: xamarin, telerik

I have the following in my XAML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input"
             xmlns:telerikDataControls="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
             xmlns:listView="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls.ListView;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
             xmlns:this="clr-namespace:Namespace123"
             x:Class="MyClass"
             BackgroundColor="#F7F7F7">
```

And...

```
 <telerikDataControls:RadListView.LayoutDefinition>
          <listView:ListViewLinearLayout>
            <listView:ListViewLinearLayout.ItemLength>
              <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                          iOS="48"
                          Android="48"
                          WinPhone="48" />
            </listView:ListViewLinearLayout.ItemLength>
            <listView:ListViewLinearLayout.VerticalItemSpacing>
              <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                          iOS="10"
                          Android="10"
                          WinPhone="2" />
            </listView:ListViewLinearLayout.VerticalItemSpacing>
          </listView:ListViewLinearLayout>
        </telerikDataControls:RadListView.LayoutDefinition>
...
```

And I get the following exception...

> Exception is: XamlParseException - Position 50:12. Type
>   listView:ListViewLinearLayout not found in xmlns
>   clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls.ListView;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls

I've cleaned the solution and deleted obj/bin folders. Why can't it find the type?

This runs fine in the code behind..

```
var list = new RadListView();

list.LayoutDefinition = new ListViewLinearLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Today when I ran the app for the first time, it worked.